# OpenCV image numbers identification

Tags: python, opencv

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sorry for bad english. I want to make condition, that image with 12 in left corner = image with 12 in right corner and != image with 21.

I need a fast way to determine this, cause there are many pics and they refresh.

I tried to use counting pixels of specific image:

```
result = np.count_nonzero(np.all(original > (0,0,0), axis=2))
```

(why I use >(0,0,0) instead of == (255,255,255)? there are grey shadows near white symbols, that eyes can't see)

This way doesn't see a difference between 12 and 21.

I tried the second way, compare new images with templates, but it one see a huge difference between 12 and 12 in left-right corners!

```
original = ('auto/5or.png' )
template= cv2.imread( 'auto/5t.png' )
res = cv2.matchTemplate( original, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED )
```

I didn't try yet some difficult method of determining digits, cause I think - this is too slow, even on my little pics. (I may mistake).

I have digits only from 0 to 30, I have all templates, examples, they are differ only with location inside black square.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the position of the digits in the image to make a difference, you can threshold the image to black and white and find the bounding box and crop to it so your digits are always in the same place - then just difference the images or use what you were using before:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image, greyscale and threshold
im=np.array(Image.open('21.png').convert('L'))

# Mask of white pixels
mask = im.copy()
mask[mask<128]  = 0     # Threshold pixels < 128 down to black

# Coordinates of white pixels
coords = np.argwhere(mask)

# Bounding box of white pixels
x0, y0 = coords.min(axis=0)
x1, y1 = coords.max(axis=0) + 1

# Crop to bbox
cropped = im[x0:x1, y0:y1]

# Save
Image.fromarray(cropped).save('result.png')
```

That gives you this:

[image]

Obviously crop your template images as well.

---

I am less familiar with **OpenCV** in Python, but it would look something like this:

```
import cv2
# Load image
img = cv2.imread('21.png',0)

# Threshold at 127
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)

# Get contours
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get bounding box
cnt = contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
```